# Custom TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have created a custom Tag Helper which is setup with a new tag on the page, i.e. `user-view`

I use this Tag Helper in the following way

```
<user-view user-view-mode="Sidebar"></user-view>
```

and would like that this tag helper create an html structure like the following

```
<div class="user-view">
   [...]
</div>
```

However when looking at the generated code I have found

```
<user-view>
    <div class="user-view">
        [...]
    </div>
</user-view>
```

Should I use `output.SetContent()` instead of `output.Content.AppendHtml()`?

Also, the `user-view-mode` parameter is of type `enum`. Is there any way to have suggestions/hints on the html about the available values?

Last question: how do I access currently connected user in my TagHelper code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the `SetContent()` method also deals with the inside of the element. The way for creating TagHelpers which introduce new tags is by replacing the tag during processing. In your case this would be something like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("user-view")]
public class UserViewTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Replace user-view with div
        output.TagName = "div";

        // Set class
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "user-view");

        // Append the inner structure
        output.Content.AppendHtml(...);
    }
}
```

Regarding the question about accessing the currently connected user I suggest you use DI. You can inject any service (registered previously with `IServiceCollection`) through standard constructor injection. Additionality `ViewContext` and `ViewComponentContext` can be injected into properties thanks to dedicated attributes.

```
public class UserViewTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    [ViewComponentContext]
    public ViewComponentContext ViewComponentContext { get; set;
}
```

Based on those you should be able to get your user.

Comment: Great. Your solution works perfectly regarding the tag question. Do you have any suggestion also regarding the last questions on the post?

Comment: @Lorenzo Sorry I've simple missed that part of question. I've added details regarding how to use DI with TagHelpers which should get you what you need. You can also find some more details abotu creating a TagHelper [here](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2016/12/content-security-policy-in-aspnet-core.html)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!